# How do I Store the Value of Table Data which is Being Passed Dynamically from PHP to JavaScript after a Button Click Event?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, getelementbyid

I've been Trying to List Users in a 1 to 1 Chat Application in HTML Tables & uniquely Define Each Table cell data by the Name ID dynamically in PHP. The problem is I am Unable to retrieve the Same Table Cell Value after a Button Click for that Particular Record even after Passing the Name value in PHP.

```
<?php

                include("functions.php");

                $token = $user_details[5];
                // Get all Users except the Logged user
                $users_list = get_users_list($user_details[2]);

                ?>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-style">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="text-center">Users List</td>
                            <td class="text-center">Login Status</td>
                            <td class="text-center"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($users_list))
                            {
                        ?>
                        <tr class="table-row-users">
                            <td class="text-center" id="<?php echo $fetch['user_name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fetch['user_name']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $fetch['user_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $fetch['user_login_status']; ?></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary receiver_email='<?php echo base64_encode($fetch["user_email"]);?>'" id="single_chat" onclick='setReceiver("<?php echo $fetch['user_name']; ?>")'>Chat</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

JavaScript Code

```
function setReceiver(receiver_name)
        {
            var to_user_name = document.getElementById(receiver_name).value;//Unable to Retrieve the Value here
            console.log(to_user_name);
            //$('.receiver').append(to_user_name);
        }
```

I am Facing the Error on the JS Side. Also this is my 1st Question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is the value of `receiver_name` when it's passed to JS?  Also, I don't believe `value` is a valid attribute on a `td` element.

Comment: `.value` should be `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`

Comment: receiver_name value comes from button click in table above